# Safari bug: translate3d scrolling is offset when input causes scrolling

Tags: safari, textarea, translate3d

There is a bug in Safari 5.1.1 on Mac which seems intractable. (Also, exhibited by Firefox on Mac.)

Using **iScroll** to set up a scrolling DIV, any scrolling caused by an **INPUT** or **TEXTAREA** offsets the translate3d matrix by the amount of automatic scrolling. Thus, for example, you may no longer be able to scroll back to the top!

Since it is the **translate3d matrix** which is incorrect, I cannot find any way of working around this bug. All values obtained from the elements appear to be correct, except that the scrolled content is incorrectly offset.

**Note also**: I am sure this is not an iScroll bug.

Any ideas are welcome! Please comment if tested in other browsers.